# HTML Help Button with image: what's the best semantic for this?

Tags: html, css, semantics

I want to create an HTML help button (that looks like an image).

What is the best semantic way to do it ?

Here's what I was thinking about:

## 1st solution:

### HTML

```
<button class='help'>
    <img/>
</button>
```

## 2nd solution:

### HTML

```
<button class='help'>
</button>
```

### CSS

```
button.help
{
    background-image:...;
}
```

## 3rd solution

### HTML

```
<img class='button' src='blabla'/>
```

I think the `button` tag is indispensable as it will behave like a button (you can click on it to get some help, basically)

Comment: its an opinion thing really, I prefer the css route since it just further seperates the presentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the button for some `form` submission, than I would prefer using

```
<input type="image" src="PATH_TO_IMAGE" alt="Submit Button" />
```

If you want to stick to the `button` tag, I would prefer using the `background-image` way.

**Why?**

Well, you can use [CSS Sprites](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/) for your website and place the image on the canvas, than map the images using `background-position` property, this way it will reduce http request by one, in fact not just one, it will save you more if you wish to have more buttons with different images later...

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

```
<button class='help'>
</button>
```

Could also add:

```
<button class="help" role="button">Help</button>
```